# JW Player any javascript interaction fails

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, interaction

I've included   jwplayer.js , and i've used jwplayer setup correctly, but still I cant use javascript functions such as play(), pause(), etc...
I'm using flash player.swf object.

Even copied the following Code but always fails.
http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16022/controlling-the-player-using-javascript

```
jwplayer("container").setup({
        file: "7.mp3",
        flashplayer: "wqplayer.swf",
        height: 270,
        width: 480
      });

<a href="" onclick="jwplayer().play();">Toggle the playback</a>
```

Comment: Share you code, error messages you receive.

Comment: Have you checked the console for javascript errors?

Comment: Yes, I did it. there are no errors. console is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you're using flash player.swf object. On JWPlayer there are three options to include media, only one of them gives you the possibility to control your player over JS:

- Using the JW Player's own JavaScript Embedder (jwplayer.js) (Recommended)
- Using a generic embedder (like ***SWFObject***)
- Using an HTML Tag like object or embed

See: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12538/supported-player-embed-methods

Afaik if you want to control yor JWPlayer through JS, there is no need for the second method and using a generic embedder (SWFObject).

See also the JS Embedder Reference: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/15995/jw-embedder-reference-guide

Make sure you don't forget the script tags around your JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/jwplayer.js"></script>

<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("container").setup({
        flashplayer: "wqplayer.swf",
        file: "7.mp3",
        height: 270,
        width: 480
    });
</script>

<a href="" onclick="jwplayer().play();">Toggle the playback</a>
```

Hope that helps!